# Using DbConfiguration class in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Will configuring my Entity Framework settings in a DBConfiguration class instead of the app.config in my data layer project give me the ability to use the data layer in the business layer without referencing Entity Framework in the business layer?

Comment: If you mean setting up things like the connection string outside of app.config then yes you can do that with no issues.

Comment: Whatever application uses your class library will still need to have whatever dependencies are needed by its direct dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes, as long as your data layer project does not expose EF specific types directly that you want to access from your business project and if you keep the required EF assemblies available in the overall solution.

But even when using the `app.config` approach in your business project you do not have to reference `EntityFramework` in your business project directly. It is sufficient, that your data layer project references it.